# jQuery selector with null context is safe?

Tags: jquery, null, selector, datacontext

There is a method where I want to find an element by class in a particular html.

```
someMethod(html) {
  $('.some-class', html).click(function(){
    ...
    })
}
```

And run it like this

```
someMethod(html)
```

Provided that html does exist(not null).

I also want to use the same method above to find for the same element through the DOM of the current page. So `html` in the method would be null.

Will it work if I run it like this?

```
someMethod()
```

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, I did. It returned me the element. Looks like it works. I'm trying to realize whether there are some pitfalls. I'm not experienced with Javascript

Comment: `someMethod()` will pass through as `$('.some-class').click`, which is perfectly valid  Your html parameter will pass from your function directly to the jquery "context" parameter.  If it's not passed, it will be `undefined` (not `null` which is subtly different, though not relevant here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see in the source code of the selector it just defaults back to `document` if an invalid context (e.g. null, false, undefined, ...) is given.

From the JQuery Source Code (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/selector.js)

```
// nodeType defaults to 9, since context defaults to document
nodeType = context ? context.nodeType : 9;
```